Why is my transaction showing as 'success' but the value is 0 ETH ($0.00)?
I am new to the bitcoin world and any help would be appreciated.
Transaction hash:  0xfba22d3b6d047bbd81d25dd5d6ef3f070f57f79abeaeb4de49e7dc605ab4cb7c
If I was scammed, is there any way to recuperate the money or trace it back to the culprits?

The transaction shows 0 ETH value because the ETH token that was transferred is simply an ERC-20 token that was named ETH, not the actual Ethereum native ETH token.
If you sent money to someone for ETH in return and received those tokens, then unfortunately you were likely scammed. Most of the time tokens are impossible to recover as well, in the future, remember to never to send money to an address, whether it be a smart contract or an EOA, that you don't completely trust.

This is a ERC-20 transfer. The token which has been transferred is a ERC-20 token not a native ETH . 
This is what the call data looks like. The first argument is to address to whom the token has been transferred to and the second parameter a value , how many tokens have been transferred. If you select Decode Input Data you will see the below details.

The amount here shown is in wei. Wei is a smallest unit of a currency like cents to the dollars.
Now if you convert this amount to Ether you will get

So this 14.16 is equals to the amount shown here

